# Count fields in a join and group results in a table

Tags: mysql, join

I have this table containing people with data about nation of orgin, birth, citizenship and sex.

```
PEOPLE
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| surname               | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sex                   | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idNatBirth            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| idNatOrigin           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| idNatCitizen          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Nations ids (birth, origin, citizenship) are joined to a nation table:

```
NATIONS
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code        | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've yet obtained three tables counting people by nations.
For the three nation fields the same model. This is for the birth:

```
select people.idNatBirth, nations.*, count(*) FROM people
INNER JOIN nations
ON nations.id = people.idNatBirth
GROUP BY nations.description;

+------------------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+
| idNatBirth       | id  | code   | description | count(*) |
+------------------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+
|              133 | 133 |      1 | AFGHANISTAN |       43 |
|              193 | 193 |     61 | IRAQ        |      139 |
|              219 | 219 |     87 | PAKISTAN    |       59 |
|              238 | 238 |    106 | SIRIA       |      161 |
+------------------+-----+--------+-------------+----------+
```

But I need a more complex result showing birth, origin, citizenship and sex distribution for each of that count.
Something like that:

```
+------------------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| description            | birth    | birthMale  | birthFem | origin     | originMale | originFem | citizenship    etc .....      
+------------------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| AFGHANISTAN            |       43 |         20 |       23 |         40 |         20 |        20 |    ....
| IRAQ                   |      139 |         39 |      100 |         29 |          9 |        20 |    ....
| PAKISTAN               |       59 |         50 |        9 |         10 |          9 |         1 |    .... 
| SIRIA                  |      161 |         61 |      100 |        102 |          2 |       100 |    ....
| ALBANIA                |        0 |          0 |        0 |         12 |         10 |         2 |    ....
| SOMALIA                |        0 |          0 |        0 |      ...
...
...
```

As you can see not every nation is present in every fields for people table...
Any idea on how accomplish that?
Thanks in advance.
This is a sample data for people table:

```
+----+------------+------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | name       | surname    | sex   | idNatBirth       | idNatOrigin          | idNatCitizen          |
+----+------------+------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | name       | surname    | M     |              133 |                 NULL |                  NULL |
|  2 | AUTOS1     | AUTOS2     | M     |              133 |                 NULL |                  NULL |
|  3 | Johari     | JAI        | F     |              193 |                  238 |                   193 |
|  4 | Bejide     | RAI        | F     |              193 |                  193 |                   193 |
|  5 | Sema       | DARSHA     | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
|  6 | Kefilwe    | LATA       | M     |              219 |                  219 |                   219 |
|  7 | Kali       | RAJAN      | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
|  8 | Tanginika  | SAXENA     | F     |              193 |                  193 |                   193 |
|  9 | Marahaba   | CHAUHAN    | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
| 10 | Malkia     | PATEL      | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
| 11 | Makena     | DHAWAN     | F     |              193 |                  193 |                   193 |
| 12 | Dziko      | NARAYAN    | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
| 13 | Anaya      | NEEL       | M     |              193 |                  193 |                   193 |
| 14 | Yahminah   | SANDEEP    | M     |              238 |                  238 |                   238 |
| 15 | Iruwa      | SEN        | M     |              219 |                  219 |                   219 |
| 16 | Abena      | MATI       | M     |              133 |                  133 |                   133 |
| 17 | Obax       | BHATT      | M     |              193 |                  193 |                   193 |
| 18 | Bikilu     | NATH       | F     |              133 |                  133 |                   133 |
| 19 | Mumbi      | SRINI      | M     |              219 |                  219 |                   219 |
| 20 | Wanjiko    | MANJU      | M     |              193 |                  238 |                   193 |
+----+------------+------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data from `people` table?

Comment: Thanks!
Just edited my post...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT description,
       SUM(birth)       birth,
       SUM(birthmale)   birthMale,
       SUM(birthfem)    birthFem,
       SUM(origin)      origin,
       SUM(originmale)  originMale,
       SUM(originfem)   originFem,
       SUM(citizenship) citizenship,
       SUM(citizenmale) citizenMale,
       SUM(citizenfem)  citizenFem
FROM  (SELECT CASE
                WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL THEN n.description
                WHEN org.id IS NOT NULL THEN org.description
                WHEN cit.id IS NOT NULL THEN cit.description
              END      description,
              SUM(CASE WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS birth,
              SUM(CASE WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) birthmale,
              SUM(CASE WHEN n.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) birthFem,
              SUM(CASE WHEN org.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS origin,
              SUM(CASE WHEN org.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) originmale,
              SUM(CASE WHEN org.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) originFem,
              SUM(CASE WHEN cit.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS citizenship,
              SUM(CASE WHEN cit.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) citizenmale,
              SUM(CASE WHEN cit.id IS NOT NULL AND people.sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) citizenFem
       FROM   people
              LEFT JOIN nations n
                     ON n.id = people.idnatbirth
              LEFT JOIN nations org
                     ON org.id = people.idnatorigin
              LEFT JOIN nations cit
                     ON cit.id = people.idnatcitizen
       GROUP  BY n.id,
                 org.id,
                 cit.id,
                 n.description,
                 org.description,
                 cit.description)t1
GROUP  BY description;
```

Hope this would help you out. This is really a simple query. Formatting the query showed it like a devil query.

Comment: Almost there! Thanks!
The only problem is that results only concern nations presents in every fields.

Comment: Almost there! Thanks!
The problem is that the query actually lists only the nations that appear in every fields: so I cannot see, for example, a nation that appears in the citizenship field...
I need to see every nations related to any of the three fields...

Comment: @Miss-Take Do you have sample data for that scenario? If so kindly update the question and let me know please.

Comment: Just add or edit an id that is not present in other fields... (in my real DB 173 = eritrea appear only in idnatorigin column) you will see that this id won't figure in the results unless it has been inserted into the three nation colums...